# objectbox flutter select specific property or get all object which have unique property value

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I have an object entity in which i store many fields including **clientNumber and clientName** .
**I know that i can use property query on the clientNumber field but i wouldn't get the clientName**,
i also know that in objectbox for java there is a filter method that might solve my problem,
but **appart from retrieving all the clients and filtering data manually i don't know any other way to do it with flutter** .

**Could you tell me if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result** ?

Thank you by advance for your answer, and for the great product that is objectbox

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at regular [queries](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries) (not property queries). I imagine it could look like something like this:

```
Query<Client> query = box.query(client_.clientName.equals('Joe')).build();
List<Client> joes = query.find();
```

Now, having a the entire object(s), you can easily access any property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what i end up doing, being used to sql database i imagined that there was another solution but i know now that it's not the case

Comment: Yes, it's a common perception coming from SQL; maybe it's worth a FAQ entry.